# How to trace strange Network calls in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the developer tools, in a web app I'm working on, I'm getting a rather strange error in the console:

'GET data:'

That's it.  No stack trace or anything.  It is a failing network call.  It shows up in the Network tab:

> Request URL: data:
>
> Request Headers
>
> Referer: http://localhost/testapp/
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.100 Safari/534.30

No error in Firefox/Firebug.  Would be nice to figure out what line of HTML/Javascript caused Chrome to attempt to execute this specific request.

Comment: Maybe it's related to new technologies, something like [Geolocation API](http://thoughtresults.com/geolocation-api) or things like that? I guess Chrome supports that feature, but Firefox doesn't.

Comment: Eh.  No.  This is a heavy AJAX app (almost everything is done via AJAX calls) and the error occurs somewhere during the component loading process - but nothing seems to fail.  I'm not doing anything with Geolocation.  The problem could reside in any number of spots in the code.  I want to walk the stack from the attempted web request back up the chain to the root that originally made the network request.  This is an important feature lacking in Firefox/Firebug too.

Comment: Hmm.  Found a related Firefox/Firebug bug tracker issue:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563623

Answer (score 10):

[image: In the Network tab, hover over the file name of the initiator and you should find the caller in the stack trace.]

In the Network tab, hover over the file name of the initiator and you should find the caller in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Found a related Chrome bug tracker issue:  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86286

So it looks like web developers are out of luck for tracing network request sources until these issues get resolved.  Both issues require their underlying engines to be modified.  So Firefox and Webkit first have to support the feature, then Firebug and Chrome can, respectively and in turn, support the feature.  New versions of both browsers (and plugin) need to be released.  And it sounds like it won't be easy to implement.